# Tourist or transit visa when visiting Kashgar and Urumqi

Tags: visas, transit-visas, china

I am planning to travel through Kyrgyzstan and Kazachstan using Kashgar and Urumqi as transit points, spending about a day in each of them. The planned route is Kashgar - Kyrgyzstan (Osh) - Kazachstan (Almaty) - Urumqi. All border crossings will be overland.

As I understand, my route doesn't qualify for [any short-term visa exemptions](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm) so as an EU citizen I require a Chinese visa. Is this correct?

Both double-entry type G (transit) and L (tourist) visa seem to apply in my case. The price is the same. Which one is the correct choice?